# iOS device does not react when it is in correct position when using UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

I have an app where I am making my iOS device make a sound when the user changes the device's position.  I have the user put the device in a flat position, landscape position, and then portrait position, and when the user puts the device in those positions at the appropriate time, the app emits a sound to confirm the position.

My problem however is that if the device is initially in the flat position (e.g. lying flat on a desk), the device does NOT make a sound.  In other words, the sound is only emitted when the user PUTS the device in that position and does not immediately sense the position that it is in already.  Is there a way for me to rectify this such that the app emits a sound if it is either initially in that position or is put into the correct position?  Here is my relevant code:

```
- (void) orientationCheck {

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(showTextOnly) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice *device = note.object;

    if(currentTest == flatTest) {

        testLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 30, 200, 150);
        [testLabel setText:@"Hold device on its side."];
        testImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 300, 200);
        testImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"accelerometer test - side.png"];

        if (device.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || device.orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {

           ...

        }

    }
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just check the device's orientation at launch time? In other words, besides registering for the notification when the device orientation *changes*, look to see what the device orientation *is*.

Comment: Err...that would make sense.  When would I do the check, before the line:  [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];  or after it, but before the line:   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];  ?

Comment: Irrelevant. Those are commands about what will happen at some future time. You want to know know what's true now.